# Static Analysis tool to detect Internationalization issues

Tags: java, internationalization, code-analysis

Are there any tools (free/commercial) that can audit an application for internationalization? (or localization-readiness, if you prefer)

Primarily interested in:

**Mulitlingual Implementation tests**

```
    Examples:  
    * [javascript] alert('Oops wrong choice!');  
    * [java] String msg = resourcebundle.getString("key.x").concat("4");  
    * [jdbc] String query=".. order by abc"; //should be NLS_SORT or equiv.
```

**Date Implementation tests**

```
    Examples:  
    * SimpleDateFormat used without Locale  
    * Apache's DateFormatUtils used
```

**Numeric Implementation  tests**

```
    Examples:
    * NumberFormat used without Locale
```

**javascript-validation tests**

```
    Examples:
    * [javascript] checkIsDecimal { //decimal point checked against "." }  
    * [javascript] hardcoded character range [A-z]
```

Cheers.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a check for each of your four categories?

Comment: I've added some examples off the top of my head. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Globalyzer - http://lingoport.com/globalyzer - as it is just that, a tool for performing static analysis on code specifically for internationalization. It works with a variety of programming languages too. Supports detection and correction for embedded strings (string externalization capabilities too), potential locale-limiting methods/functions/classes depending upon the programming language and requirements, as well as other issues like programming patterns and embedded images. There are default "rule sets" which get you a good start, and then you can customize your rules for both detection and filtering of issues. Plus there's an underlying database that helps you tag or keep track of i18n issues as you work with them. There's a server component, where you create and share your rule sets with your team members, then desktop and command line clients which run locally on your machine to analyze your source, so you're not sending any code or reporting off your local machine.

Comment: Interesting.. Can you confirm with your team (based on your profile, I'm assuming you are from lingoport) that it will catch all the problems I've listed in my question. I will accept your answer post a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your examples, you mostly want to diagnose
functions that produce output, whose input isn't somehow
internationalized.

So for the alert case, you want to find any print call
that acquires a string that is not produced by
one of possibly several well-know translation routines.

For the jdbc case, you want to identify ordering constraints
that are not locale specific.

For the various date cases, you want date routines that
are known to produce locale-specific answers.

The javascript validation is harder to guess at intent;
presumaly you want to diagnose functions that are known
to be wired to a particular locale; this seems a lot like
the date case.  For range checks, you want capture anything
that compares a character to another for less or greater than.

For the wired-locale functions, it seems just knowing their
name would be enough (although perhaps there has to be some overload resolution,
e.g., by number of arguments), so NumberFormat(?,?) is bad,
and NumberFormat(?,?,?) is OK.

Why can't you write a regular expression to look (hueristically) for the bad cases?

For the range case, you just need to recognize expressions
of the form of  [exp] < [literal-char]  or [exp] < [literal-string].
A regexp to look for just "< '.+" would seem adequate.

Are there common cases that these would miss?

EDIT (from comment below: "I've been using regexp but...")
If you want a tool that is deeper than regexp, you pretty much
have to go to language parsing, name/type resolution, and having
data flow analysis would be helpful.   Since you want to process
multiple (computer) languages, the tool has to be multi-lingual capable.
And it appears you want to be able to customize it to check for
the specific cases relevant to your application.

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) 
has all these properties, including
parsers for Java, JavaScript and SQL.   It is designed to be customized,
so you have to do that in advance of using it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have been using regex to look for these bad cases but would love a pmd,findbugs-type of software. Makes for good continuous integration component

Comment: Can you show a specific case that regexp does poorly?  I've added the description of a much more sophisticated analysis engine, but you don't really want to go there if regexps are good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had studied IntelliJ IDEA's code analyzers, and it does have those that you requested. It's a commercial IDE, specialized in java, but knows other languages as well.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections.jsp doesnt do points 3 and 4.